# STM32G431 Instruction Pointer in System Memory (0x1fff4be0)

Tags: stm32, hardware, bootloader, gpio, boot

I am using an STM32G431CB (and the HAL) to record ADC data data using DMA, control/read GPIOs, communicate via I2C and USB CDC (virtual comm port), and use timers. I have verified that each of these peripherals work correctly individually both on a dev board (NUCLEO-G431KB) and on my custom board with the 48 pin version of the same chip (STM32G431CB).

However, the problem that I am running into is that the program will occasionally jump to an instruction at address 0x1fff4be0. This is in system memory. After inspecting disassembly, I don't see any instruction that would cause it to branch here. In different versions of this program with one or few of the peripherals running, this jump has happened when calling different HAL functions including:

- HAL_GPIO_ReadPin
- HAL_GPIO_WritePin
- HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit
- HAL_ADC_Start_DMA

I don't think that there is any correlation between the function called and the jump to system memory.

What can cause the STM32 to do this? I am trying to use PB8-BOOT0 as a GPIO output. When I leave PB8-BOOT0 unconfigured (reset state), I do not run into this issue.

main.c:

```
#include "main.h"
#include "usb_device.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include <stdint.h>
#include "mymain.h"
#include "usbd_cdc_if.h"
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc1;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_adc1;

I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c3;

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim6;
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim7;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
static void MX_I2C3_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM7_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM6_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
uint16_t ADC_result[4]; // ADC results: {TEMP_SENSOR, AC_CHG, R_SLIDER, L_SLIDER}
uint8_t I2Cdata;
uint8_t USB_tx_buffer[24];
struct SB_data SB1;
struct SB_data SB2;
uint16_t GPIO_data = 0x00c0;
/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_I2C3_Init();
  MX_USB_Device_Init();
  MX_TIM7_Init();
  MX_TIM6_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_adc1);

  TPS55288Q1_Init();

  // GPIO initial states
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_RESET); // Initialize USB 3 hub in reset until tablet supplies power on TAB_DCOUT->VBUS_DET3V3 (PA2)
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_10, GPIO_PIN_RESET); // Initialize 5V, 3.3V, 2.5V, 1.2V supplies off (net Enable_Power)
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_RESET); // Initialize L mouse off
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_SET); // Enable EN_EXT_USB_PWR by default
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_11, GPIO_PIN_SET); // DISABLE_CHG1
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_12, GPIO_PIN_SET); // DISABLE_CHG2

  // BEGIN TESTING ONLY //
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_10, GPIO_PIN_SET);
  // END TESTING ONLY //

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
      // ADC DMA Start
      //HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, (uint32_t*) ADC_result, 4);

      // Log GPIO data
      log_GPIO_data();

    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);
  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = RCC_PLLM_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 12;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = RCC_PLLQ_DIV4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = RCC_PLLR_DIV2;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief ADC1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 0 */

  ADC_MultiModeTypeDef multimode = {0};
  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 1 */
  /** Common config
  */
  hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV2;
  hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc1.Init.GainCompensation = 0;
  hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SEQ_CONV;
  hadc1.Init.LowPowerAutoWait = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 4;
  hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
  hadc1.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.Overrun = ADC_OVR_DATA_OVERWRITTEN;
  hadc1.Init.OversamplingMode = DISABLE;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure the ADC multi-mode
  */
  multimode.Mode = ADC_MODE_INDEPENDENT;
  if (HAL_ADCEx_MultiModeConfigChannel(&hadc1, &multimode) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure Regular Channel
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_1;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_1;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_2CYCLES_5;
  sConfig.SingleDiff = ADC_SINGLE_ENDED;
  sConfig.OffsetNumber = ADC_OFFSET_NONE;
  sConfig.Offset = 0;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure Regular Channel
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_2;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_2;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure Regular Channel
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_4;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_3;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure Regular Channel
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_TEMPSENSOR_ADC1;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_4;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief I2C3 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_I2C3_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C3_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C3_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C3_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C3_Init 1 */
  hi2c3.Instance = I2C3;
  hi2c3.Init.Timing = 0x00303D5B;
  hi2c3.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
  hi2c3.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c3.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
  hi2c3.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
  hi2c3.Init.OwnAddress2Masks = I2C_OA2_NOMASK;
  hi2c3.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
  hi2c3.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure Analogue filter
  */
  if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigAnalogFilter(&hi2c3, I2C_ANALOGFILTER_ENABLE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure Digital filter
  */
  if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigDigitalFilter(&hi2c3, 0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C3_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C3_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief TIM6 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM6_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM6_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM6_Init 0 */

  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM6_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM6_Init 1 */
  htim6.Instance = TIM6;
  htim6.Init.Prescaler = 1600-1;
  htim6.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim6.Init.Period = 19999;
  htim6.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim6) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim6, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM6_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM6_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief TIM7 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM7_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM7_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM7_Init 0 */

  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM7_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM7_Init 1 */
  htim7.Instance = TIM7;
  htim7.Init.Prescaler = 1600-1;
  htim7.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim7.Init.Period = 121;
  htim7.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim7) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim7, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM7_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM7_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * Enable DMA controller clock
  */
static void MX_DMA_Init(void)
{

  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMAMUX1_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA1_Channel1_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel1_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel1_IRQn);

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4|GPIO_PIN_10, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_11|GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PA4 PA10 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_4|GPIO_PIN_10;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PB2 PB11 PB12 PB8 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_11|GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_8;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

// Initializes TPS55288Q1 buck-boost converters by configuring external voltage divider, resetting error flags, and disabling output
void TPS55288Q1_Init() {
    I2Cdata = 0b10000011;
    HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c3, TPS55288Q1_TAB_DCIN_DEV_ADDR<<1, TPS55288Q1_VOUT_FS_ADDR, 1, &I2Cdata, 1, 2); // Use external voltage divider
    HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c3, TPS55288Q1_12V_DEV_ADDR<<1, TPS55288Q1_VOUT_FS_ADDR, 1, &I2Cdata, 1, 2);

    HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c3, TPS55288Q1_TAB_DCIN_DEV_ADDR<<1, TPS55288Q1_STATUS_R, 1, &I2Cdata, 1, 2); // Read and reset error flags
    HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c3, TPS55288Q1_12V_DEV_ADDR<<1, TPS55288Q1_STATUS_R, 1, &I2Cdata, 1, 2);

    I2Cdata = 0b00100000; // ~OE, all else default
    HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c3, TPS55288Q1_TAB_DCIN_DEV_ADDR<<1, TPS55288Q1_MODE_R_ADDR, 1, &I2Cdata, 1, 2);
    HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c3, TPS55288Q1_12V_DEV_ADDR<<1, TPS55288Q1_MODE_R_ADDR, 1, &I2Cdata, 1, 2);
}

// switches the channel being read on ADC1
void ADC1_Select_Channel(uint32_t channel) {
    ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};
    sConfig.Channel = channel;
    sConfig.Rank = 1;
    sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_12CYCLES_5;
    if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }
}

// reads GPIO inputs that will be transmitted to the tablet
// {DISABLE_CHG2, DISABLE_CHG1, ~BATID2, ~BATID1, RB2, RB1, LB2, LB1}
void log_GPIO_data() {
    GPIO_data &= 0xffc0; // clear bottom 6 bits
    GPIO_data |= HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_6) | (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_7) << 1) |
                (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_0) << 2) | (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_1) << 3) |
                (!HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_13) << 4) | (!HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOF, GPIO_PIN_1) << 5);
}

void set_bit(uint16_t* data, uint8_t bit_pos, uint8_t value) {
    if (value) {
        *data |= 1<<bit_pos;
    } else {
        *data &= ~(1<<bit_pos);
    }
}

// Returns 1 if either battery is inserted and not fully discharged or if AC_CHG_Det is 1. Indicates active power source
uint8_t PWRsource_det() {
    return (bat1_inserted() && (SB1.status[0] & 0x10)) || (bat2_inserted() && (SB2.status[0] & 0x10)) || (GPIO_data & 0x0100);
}

// Returns 1 if Smart Battery 1 is inserted, 0 otherwise
uint8_t bat1_inserted() { // internal pull down resistor on smart battery when detected. Pin is low when battery is inserted
    return GPIO_data & (1<<4);
}

// Returns 1 if Smart Battery 2 is inserted, 0 otherwise
uint8_t bat2_inserted() { // internal pull down resistor on smart battery when detected. Pin is low when battery is inserted
    return GPIO_data & (1<<5);
}

// loads the USB CDC transmission buffer. Multi-byte data fields are Little Endian. Ends in \n\r.
void load_USB_TX_buffer(uint8_t* TX_buffer, struct SB_data* bat1, struct SB_data* bat2, uint16_t* ADC_readings, uint16_t GPIO_inputs, uint16_t temperature) {
    TX_buffer[0]  = bat1->status[0];
    TX_buffer[1]  = bat1->status[1];
    TX_buffer[2]  = bat1->timetoempty[0];
    TX_buffer[3]  = bat1->timetoempty[1];
    TX_buffer[4]  = bat1->voltage[0];
    TX_buffer[5]  = bat1->voltage[1];
    TX_buffer[6]  = bat1->chgpercent;
    TX_buffer[7]  = bat2->status[0];
    TX_buffer[8]  = bat2->status[1];
    TX_buffer[9]  = bat2->timetoempty[0];
    TX_buffer[10] = bat2->timetoempty[1];
    TX_buffer[11] = bat2->voltage[0];
    TX_buffer[12] = bat2->voltage[1];
    TX_buffer[13] = bat2->chgpercent;
    TX_buffer[14] = (uint8_t) (ADC_readings[1] >> 8); // Right slider
    TX_buffer[15] = (uint8_t) ADC_readings[1];
    TX_buffer[16] = (uint8_t) (ADC_readings[0] >> 8); // Left Slider
    TX_buffer[17] = (uint8_t) ADC_readings[0];
    TX_buffer[18] = (uint8_t) (temperature >> 8); // Temperature sensor
    TX_buffer[19] = (uint8_t) temperature;
    TX_buffer[20] = (uint8_t) (GPIO_inputs & 0xff);
    TX_buffer[21] = (uint8_t) ((GPIO_inputs >> 8) & 0xff);
    TX_buffer[22] = (uint8_t) '\n';
    TX_buffer[23] = (uint8_t) '\r';
}

void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef* htim) {
    if (htim == &htim6) { // USB RX Comms 2s timeout
        HAL_TIM_Base_Stop_IT(&htim7); // Stop USB TX
        HAL_TIM_Base_Stop_IT(&htim6);
        // disable 12V and TAB_DCIN
        uint8_t data = 0b00100000; // ~OE, all else default
        HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c3, TPS55288Q1_TAB_DCIN_DEV_ADDR<<1, TPS55288Q1_MODE_R_ADDR, 1, &data, 1, 10);
        data = 0b00100100; // ~OE, address=0x75, all else default
        HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c3, TPS55288Q1_12V_DEV_ADDR<<1,      TPS55288Q1_MODE_R_ADDR, 1, &data, 1, 10);
        // disable 5V, 3.3V, 2.5V, 1.2V supplies (net Enable_Power)
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_10, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    } else if (htim == &htim7) { // USB TX call (82Hz)
        uint16_t temperature = __HAL_ADC_CALC_TEMPERATURE(3300, ADC_result[3], ADC_RESOLUTION_12B);
        load_USB_TX_buffer(USB_tx_buffer, (struct SB_data*) &SB1, (struct SB_data*) &SB2, (uint16_t*) ADC_result, GPIO_data, temperature);
        CDC_Transmit_FS(USB_tx_buffer, sizeof(USB_tx_buffer));
        /*         ** UART DEBUG **
        uint8_t usart_d[] = "SRS\n\r";
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, usart_d, sizeof(usart_d), 2);
        */
    }
}

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

Comment: What is in the debugger backtrace? failing that put a breakpoint on the address and check the link register?

Answer (score 0):

Your microcontroller is executing the embedded bootloader.

Depending on the micro that can be caused by one or more of the following:

- Obtion byte settings
- BOOT0 pin
- Content of the first word of flash during BOR.

Option byte are loaded only on BOR if an update is not explicited called through  OBL_LAUNCH. Flash empty flag (the last point) is also only evaluated during BOR. No update is possible without BOR. You can exit bootloader with an approriate command via bootloader interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Probably due to the fact you are using BOOT0 as a GPIO (unless it is a specific feature of the STM32G4, I know only H7 and L4).

I think if a reset occurs for whatever reason , and the signal is at the wrong state, you will end up booting on System Flash.

Comment: That's a good point. Depending on the electronics used on that pin, if you got a reset during use it could trigger the bootloader entry. You can inhibit bootloader entry by boot0 pin on some devices by option bytes. ( NSWBOOT0 on STM32L496/A6 )